# Detecting any changes on latest snapshot

Tags: zfs

Is there a way to quickly check whether there are any changes made on top of the latest snapshot? The goal is to know whether taking another snapshot is necessary.

I have tried `zfs diff $LATEST_SNAPSHOT` but that approach seems unnecessarily complex since it prints everything, when I need a simple yes/no answer. Furthermore, `zfs diff` does not work on unmounted encrypted datasets.

Comment: *Furthermore, `zfs diff` does not work on unmounted encrypted datasets.*  What do you expect would work on an unmounted encrypted dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `zfs get -o written <dataset>` to see how much data has been written to `<dataset>` since its most recent snapshot was taken. If that value is zero, nothing has changed and you don't need another snapshot.

I think you might also be able to do it using the `zfs get -o usedby*` properties too, but I'm a little unclear about which one you'd want. If you want to try it, [the `zfsprops` man page](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/7/zfsprops.7.html) has very detailed descriptions of how space is accounted across those -- just search the page for `usedby*`.